# "Will it show under X"

Tags: grammar

Is it just me or is there something wrong with the sentence below. I saw something like this recently:

> If I upload something from the backend, will it **show** under Latest?

I don't know but the word *show* sounds a bit strange here. Any thoughts?

Comment: From a programming standpoint, "show" is perfectly idiomatic. In fact, "show" is often a reserved word in databases used for, well, showing things. From a user standpoint, it's not so great. Personally, I would use the word "display".

Answer (score 3):

> If I upload something from the backend, will it show under Latest?

I think there is a slight US bias to this form of words but it is perfectly understandable in the UK.

Other possibilities

*If I upload something from the backend, will it show up under Latest?*

or more formally

*If I upload something from the backend, will it appear under Latest?*

Comment: Yes, "show" was short for "show up", meaning "appear".